# Removing console.log in production React JS with WebPack / Babel

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I would like to keep console.log in developer builds, but in production builds I want them removed.

`babel-plugin-transform-remove-console`

I cannot remember if I installed it as --save or --save-dev (and not quite sure the difference). I also do not know how to check how it was installed, but it is in my node_modules directory as `babel-plugin-transform-remove-console`.

Whether I use `npm run dev` or `npm run build` to build my project I still see the console.log statements. I would have expected the `npm run build` command to remove the console.log files.

My .babelrc file looks like this:

```
{
  "presets" : ["env", "stage-0", "react"],
  "env" : {
    "production": {
      "plugins": ["transform-remove-console"]
    }
  }
}
```

The pertinent parts of my package.json look like this:

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack -d --watch",
    "build": "webpack -p"
  },
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "babel-plugin-transform-remove-console": "^6.9.2",
    ...
  }
```

Why is the `npm run build` not removing console.log statements for me?

Answer (score 1):

`-p` is a flag for Webpack itself. Babel doesn't know anything about it. If you want your Webpack config to toggle behavior based on it, you'd need to do that yourself.

```
// webpack.config.js
module.exports = function(env) {
  return {
    // ...
    module: {
      rules: [{
        loader: "babel-loader",
        options: {
          forceEnv: env.production ? "production" : "development"
        }
      }],
    },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

> I cannot remember if I installed it as `--save` or `--save-dev` (and not quite sure the difference).

Just look at your package.json file.

`-- save` will make your package appear in **dependencies** (this is the default behaviour if no option was provided)

`-- save-dev` will make your package appear in **devDependencies**

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install

Answer (score 0):

When you use run `webpack -p`, webpack sets `process.env.NODE_ENV = "production"`, but Babel expects `process.env.BABEL_ENV = "production"`.

Comment: Okay, so what should I do to get around this?

Comment: You can set `process.env.BABEL_ENV = "production"` directly in `webpack.config.prod.js`. Or `SET BABEL_ENV="production" && webpack -p` in terminal script.

Comment: Webpack sets `NODE_ENV` in the user's compiled files, not in the executing process containing the loader.  Using `NODE_ENV` is fine, you just need to set it for the loader process.

Comment: I think you're right about where `NODE_ENV` is set.
But `BABEL_ENV` fallback to `NODE_ENV`?